# Js code not working on firefox mobile version

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

My Js code function is not working on firefox mobile android :

```
const FsEvent = class {
  called = false;

  constructor() {}

  fullScreenEvent(){
    if(this.called == false){
      var called = false;

      var arrow_left = document.getElementById("arrow-left");
      var arrow_right =document.getElementById("arrow-right");
      var fsButton = document.getElementById("fullScreen");

      arrow_left.parentElement.remove();
      arrow_right.parentElement.remove();
      fsButton.parentElement.remove();

      this.called = true;
    }
    else {
      var arrow_left = document.createElement('img');
      var arrow_right = document.createElement('img');
      var fsButton = document.createElement('img');

      var a1 = document.createElement('a');
      var a2 = document.createElement('a');
      var a3 = document.createElement('a');

      arrow_left.src = base_url + "css/arrow-left.png";
      arrow_right.src = base_url + "css/arrow-right.png";
      fsButton.src = base_url + "css/fs.png";

      arrow_left.id = "arrow-left";
      arrow_right.id = "arrow-right";
      fsButton.id = "fullScreen";

      a1.appendChild(arrow_left);
      a2.appendChild(arrow_right);
      a3.appendChild(fsButton);

      var carrouselControls = document.getElementById('carouselExampleControls');
      carrouselControls.appendChild(a1);
      carrouselControls.appendChild(a2);

      var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container-")[0];
      container.appendChild(a3);

      this.called = false;
    }
  }
}
```

This where I use it in my js script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let fsEvent = new FsEvent();
  $('#arrow-right').click(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel('next');
  });

  $('#arrow-left').click(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel('prev');
  });

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == "37"){
      $("#arrow-left").click()
    }
    else {
      if(e.keyCode == "39"){
        $("#arrow-right").click()
      }
      else {
        if(e.keyCode == "122"){
          fsEvent.fullScreenEvent();
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I tried to comment this class and all the related code. And the button event show in my web page was working great. But when I got this class in my web page the js code doesn't work at all in on the firefox mobile version. 
But the code with the class is working on opera mobile and chrome mobile.

Any idea ?

Comment: `var called = false;` <-- why even have that?

Comment: Did you debug and try to figure out what is not working?

Comment: If this works on other browsers and just not on your mobile firefox then it's likely that it may not be supported by the browser you have. Try upgrading the browser or use another one to see if it works on that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/about:debugging

Comment: Ok ty, I deleted this object in My code, it looks like it wasn't compatible with the browser.